# CountIf blank cells and formulas

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, countif

My issue is, I want to exclude blank cells using  `countif` function for VBA.

There are around 65 rows but if I put a range `K2:K1000` it calculates every blank cells whereas I need to calculate only used cells in excel. New cells will be added and therefore without changing anything I need to put the results according to the used cell automatical via click command button.

How I can do this via VBA code ? I try to used dynamic range but due to blank cells for some of the rows it did not works. Your support will be appreciated

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Range("A3") = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("K:K"))Range("K9:K1000").Rows.Count
    Range("A4") = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("K9:K1000"), "")
End Sub
```

Comment: If you need to count only to row 65 why you are using 1000 as final row?

Comment: Because it is a shared folder and therefore everyone can add new row that file. I do not want to change the range manually everytime for both formula.

Comment: This `Range("A3") = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("K:K"))Range("K9:K1000").Rows.Count` is no valid syntax and won't even compile!

Comment: That formula gives me the ratio for filled cells and row number. I need to convert that formula for dynamic range as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try find the last row in column K dynamically:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim lLastRow As Long

    ' This give you the last used row in column K of the Active Sheet.
    lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row

    ' This is the same function you were using.
    Range("A3") = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("K9:K" & lLastRow), "<>")
    Range("A4") = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("K9:K" & lLastRow), "")


End Sub
```

Comment: this is what I want.. Appreciate for your support. How I can do this forRange("A3") = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("K:K"))Range("K9:K1000").Rows.Count

Comment: What do you want to show in Range("A3")? Is it not the same as in Range("A4") or you just want to count amount of rows (blanks or not)?

Comment: @GamzeUral have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48808723/3219613) you just need to adjust the column number there (replace 2 with 11)

Comment: I need ;  number of cell that contain value / number of rows for range that wre using.( this has to be work according to the dynamic as above)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ your solution shows every empty cell in the whole column. I don't think that's not the desire outcome.

Comment: @AlexMartinez I'm pretty sure he doesn't even know himself what he wants if he usese `Range("K:K")` and `Range("K9:K1000")` at the same time in an invalid syntax.

Comment: @peh this is not I want.. I need a ratio that only shows me non blanck cells.

Comment: @GamzeUral how about putting in some effort yourself instead of waiting for a solution and let others do your work that you can just copy. It is everything here you need. Just put some effort in and you got it.

Comment: And this "*I need a ratio that only shows me non blanck cells*" dosen't make sense at all. A ratio can only be formed out of 2 values. You can only count blank cells or non blank cells and you can then form a ratio of these. We already showed how to count blank and non blank cells so I'm sure it is no mathematical challenge to form a ratio out of these 2.

Comment: Yes, once you have the two values should be pretty simple to get the ratio.

Comment: @GamzeUral if the answer fix your problem, please mark as resolved.

Comment: @AlexMartinez,thanks for your support it is fix my problem and I marked as resolved. But I have one issue that I could not fix. When I filter the column that formula is not working properly. Is there any way to handle this issue ?

Comment: You might need to convert the formulas to values i order to filter the column.

Comment: just use WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("K9:K1000"))

Answer (score 2):

This is how to count the non-empty values in the second column (`B`):

```
Sub TestMe()    
    Range("A3") = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(2))
End Sub
```

And for counting the blanks:

```
Range("A4") = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Columns(2))
```

Comment: and for counting the blanks `WorksheetFunction.CountBlank`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - Exactly! :)

Comment: These guys have it, you subtract the blank count from the non blank count to get the number of cells not blank (>0).  I just did this somewhere in my code, let me find it, as when making a column of unique names you often get a blank . . . .tempLR is a last row variable that gets used each for each monthly sheet, so it changes . . .  *holderCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWB.Worksheets("August").Range("AA1:AA" & tempLR)) _
         - Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(ThisWB.Worksheets("August").Range("AA1:AA" & tempLR))*

Answer (score 1):

If you have a static range that you want to check (or create a dynamic range with .end(xlUp) as some have suggested already) this function should work alright.

```
Public Sub CountPopulatedCells()

    Dim wb          As Workbook
    Dim ws          As Worksheet
    Dim lrow        As Long
    Dim checkRng    As Range
    Dim outputRng   As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Set outputRng = ws.Range("C3")

    'Finds the last populated row in given column
    lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Creates a range using the previously created "lrow"
    Set checkRng = ws.Range("A2:A" & lrow)

    'Calls the function and feeds it "myRng" and puts the result in "outputRng"
    outputRng.Value = CountNonBlanks(checkRng)

End Sub

Public Function CountNonBlanks(rng As Range) As Integer

    Dim cell As Range

    'Zeros the ingteger before counting
    CountNonBlanks = 0

    'Checks each cell in range given (in this case "rng")
    For Each cell In rng

        'Checks if the cell is empty or not
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then

            'Adds 1 to the output integer for each non-empty cell
            CountNonBlanks = CountNonBlanks + 1

        End If

    Next

End Function
```

I've found that using xlCellTypeConstants and WorksheetFunction throws up strange errors sometimes. I'm sure there's a simple reason as to why they do (and it's probably my fault) but I've never had any problems with the above.

This function will loop through each cell in the specified range and add the value 1 to the function output integer. Each time you run the macro the integer will zero itself.

Edit1: The reason I've chosen to inject "rng" into the function as opposed to creating it within the function itself is so that you can use it with several different ranges throughout your main sub.

Edit2: I added the sub itself which would call the function, as well as a few comments on what each part does.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many empty cells in column K as opposed to your usedrange, then this will do that:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
Dim Lastrow As Long, useRange As Long
Lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column K
useRange = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
'get the last row with data on your UsedRange    
MsgBox "Your ratio of empty cells in Column K is: " & Lastrow & "/" & useRange
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Range("A3") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(11).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
Range("A4") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(11).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
End Sub
```